# Counter examples of $|m^*(A)-m^*(B)|\le d(A, B)$ if $m^*(B)=\infty$, where $m^*$ is an outer measure and $d$ is a semi-metric

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $m^*$ be an outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. for $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ then:

$$
m^*(A):=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathscr{l}(I_n): I_n\text{ is an open interval and } A\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\ I_n\right\}.
$$

Define a semi-metric $d: \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})\to [0, \infty]$ by $d(A, B)=m^*(A \Delta B)$, where $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference.

Given that, I need to show the following property is true:

> Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, if $m^*(B)\lt \infty$ then $|m^*(A)-m^*(B)|\le d(A, B)$.

In my proof the condition $m^*(B)\lt \infty$ is not being used at all, for which I'm suspecting that I'm missing something. So if this condition is necessary, is there any counter-example for the inequality for the case $m^*(B)=\infty$?

Comment: $m^{*}(B)<\infty$ ensures that the left side of the inequality makes sense. If $A=B=\mathbb R$ then LHS is not even defined and RHS is $0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, then it's necessary to also require $m^*(A)\lt\infty$?

Comment: No, the inequality holds even if $m^{*}(A)=\infty$ as long as $m^{*}(B)<\infty$.

Comment: Ahh right, I could have said $A$ and $B$ didn't both equal $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $A=\mathbb R, B=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Sorry, my typo, I mean $m^*(A)$ and $m^*(B)$ not both equal $\infty$. I mentally typed it out with your first example in mind.